# Ubuntu (16.04) takes a little longer to shutdown and leaves the diode on the router on

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

Up until recently, whenever I clicked the shutdown icon, it would display the screen with a progress bar that consists of five dots, it would reach the second dot and then the hard drive would make a click noise and the computer would turn itself off and its LAN diode on the router would go out. But now whenever Ubuntu shuts down, it reaches the second dot, the hard drive makes the click noise but the computer doesn't actually turn itself off until reaching the fourth dot, and then the diode on the router is still on and remains that way until you unplug the computer and the router for a moment. What could possibly be the reason behind it?